# IP address of spiders and “official” web bots

Tags: web-hosting, scraping

Is there an official API to [iplists.com](http://iplists.com/) from where I can get the list of spiders?

My intention is to whitelist these IPs for site scraping.

Comment: Does `robots.txt` not work as expected for these bots? I would guess the bots IPs could change without notice.

Comment: Ask them if there's an official anything. I don't see mention of one on the site...

Comment: These lists where updated last four years ago. I assume it's safe to consider this resource dead and irrelevant.

Comment: @jscott I think the problem he's trying to solve is "I want to allow bots to site scrape / crawl as fast as they want, but I want to stop *other people* from snarfing my content (bloody leeches!)" -- If that's the case `robots.txt` won't help because the leeches will just ignore it :-/

Answer (score 8):

Not that I know of, and it could change at any time at the discretion of the bot operators.

[Google offers some specific guidance and explanation on this](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html):

> The problem with that is that if/when the IP ranges of our crawlers change, not everyone will know to check. In fact, the crawl team migrated Googlebot IPs a couple years ago and it was a real hassle alerting webmasters who had hard-coded an IP range.

and they suggest using a DNS check (forward *and* reverse) to verify:

> Telling webmasters to use DNS to verify on a case-by-case basis seems
>   like the best way to go. I think the recommended technique would be to
>   do a reverse DNS lookup, verify that the name is in the googlebot.com
>   domain, and then do a corresponding forward DNS->IP lookup using that
>   googlebot.com name; eg:
>
> `$ host 66.249.66.1`
>   `1.66.249.66.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com.`
>
> `$ host crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com`
>   `crawl-66-249-66-1.googlebot.com has address 66.249.66.1`
>
> I don't think just doing a reverse DNS lookup is sufficient, because a
>   spoofer could set up reverse DNS to point to
>   crawl-a-b-c-d.googlebot.com.

This is probably the best general advice, but it is somewhat resource intensive (CPU cycles for DNS lookups).

Comment: As an aside, this works great in theory, but it can fail spectacularly in practice. For instance, it is not possible to do this _reliably_ in PHP due to a [design flaw](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53092) in the language.

Answer (score 2):

There's no list of IP addresses for "good" search engine bots that I know of, and if there were it would be horribly out of date pretty quickly, as you've already discovered.

One thing you *can* do is to create a bot trap. This is simple in theory: You create a page that is linked to in your web site but hidden from normal users (e.g. via CSS tricks) and then `Disallow` it in `robots.txt`. You then [wait a week](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5253488/1068283) since legitimate search engines may cache `robots.txt` for that long, then start banning anything that hits the trap page (e.g. with fail2ban).

Answer (score 1):

Google bot: https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json

Bing bot: https://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingbot.json

Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler/